# Is this syntax - [x] = ‘y’ in an array literal - standard C?

Tags: c, syntax

```
const char Table[256] = {
     ['a'] = 'a', ['A'] = 'a',
     ['b'] = 'b', ['B'] = 'b',
     ['c'] = 'c', ['C'] = 'c',
     ['d'] = 'd', ['D'] = 'd',
     ['e'] = 'e', ['E'] = 'e',
     ['f'] = 'f', ['f'] = 'f',
     ['g'] = 'g', ['g'] = 'g',
     ['h'] = 'h', ['H'] = 'h',
     ['i'] = 'i', ['I'] = 'i',
     ['j'] = 'j', ['J'] = 'j',
     /* Etc */
};
```

I have seen something like that in an answer to a C question. Is this Lua-like syntax standard C, or is it some compiler extension?

Comment: This is a designated initializer which was introduced in the C99 standard, I believe.

Comment: Detail: C defines _stirng literal_ and _compound literal_, but not _array literal_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that syntax is standard since the C99 (the 1999 ISO C standard).

It's described in the C standard: [https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9)

(The link is to an HTML version of the N1570 draft, which is very close to the published 2011 edition.)

Designated initializers can also be used for struct and union members, with the syntax `.name = value` rather than `[index] = value`.

Designated initializers can also be used in *compound literals*: [https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.5](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.5)